# Maintaining clean history after PR comments

Tags: git, github, gitlab, workflow

I've been using a combination of `git add --patch` and `git rebase --interactive` to maintain a clean git history before creating a PR.

For example:

```
commit 1: Add feature 1
commit 2: Add feature 2
```

When others review my PR, they might might request a change to feature 1, in which case I'd like to make that change, and still maintain the commit structure I already have.

I'd probably do something like commit the changes requested, then do `git rebase -i` and squash the last commit into the first commit

Before:

```
commit 1: Add feature 1
commit 2: Add feature 2
commit 3: Amend feature 1
```

After:

```
commit 1: Add feature 1 (now with requested change)
commit 2: Add feature 2
```

Now I have to do `git push --force` but this will erase all of the comments so the reviewer won't get the chance to sign off on the changes. Does anyone have a way around this?

Comment: This depends entirely upon the Git hosting provider you are using. Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) / Azure DevOps Server, for example, retains all the existing PR comments. I do not know about GitHub or GitLab.

Comment: Open a new PR and link to the old one, or dont force push (ie dont rebase for reviewer feedback)

Comment: Or just make fixup commits (e.g. with `git commit --fixup=...`) and push it. Do `git rebase --autosquash` and force-push after approval / before merging.

Comment: @alfunx Thanks! This is ultimately what I was looking for because Github attaches comments to commits so fixup leaves the original comments intact.